# Understand how callback methods of CacheWriterAdapter work

Tags: java, spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Spring Boot Version - 1.5.2,

Gemfire version - 8.2.6 (Overriding the managed version 8.2.2),

RegionType - PARTITION_REDUNDANT,

Proxy - ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY,

Database - Cassandra

We are extending CacheWriterAdapter and overriding beforeCreate(), beforeUpdate(), beforeDestroy(). We are connecting to remote gemfire server using JAVA.

```
@Bean(name = GemfireConstants.DEFAULT_GEMFIRE_CACHE_NAME)
ClientCache gemfireCache(@Qualifier("gemfireProperties") Properties gemfireProperties,
        @Value("${gemfire.locator1:localhost}") String locatorHost,
        @Value("${gemfire.port1:10334}") int locatorPort) {

    ClientCache gemfireCache = new ClientCacheFactory(gemfireProperties).addPoolLocator(locatorHost, locatorPort)
            .setPdxSerializer(pdxSerializer()).setPdxReadSerialized(false).create();

    return gemfireCache;
}
```

but for HTTP GET, PUT and POST every time beforeCreate() is invoked. However for HTTP DELETE beforeDestroy() is invoked. We also tried printing the boolean values from com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/Operation and detailed analysis is at the bottom.
We want to understand

- why beforeUpdate is never invoked
- why isGet, isContanisKey is false for HTTP GET operation when data is present in gemfire cache
- Why isCreate is false for HTTP POST operation
- Why isUpdate is false for hTTP PUT operation
- Why old value is not fetched for HTTP PUT operation

**Scenario -1**
Gemfire - No records

Cassandra - Record available

Test Case - HTTP GET service called using existing data which is available in Cassandra not in Gemfire

Result - Cache Loader is invoked first and then CacheWriterAdapter's beforeCreate() invoked with operation as Local_LOAD_CREATE

getNewValue- Object fetched

getOldValue- null

IsLoad-true

IsLocalLoad-true

IsLocal-false

isGetEntry-false

isSearchOrLoad-true

isUpdate-false

isCreate-true

isDestroy-false

isGet-false

isGetEntry-false

isContainsKey-false

isContainsValue-false

isContainsValueForKey-false

**Scenario -2**

Gemfire - Record Available

Cassandra - Record available

Test Case - HTTP GET service called using existing data which is available in both Cassandra and Gemfire

Result - CacheWriterAdapter's beforeCreate() invoked with operation as Local_LOAD_CREATE

getNewValue- Object fetched

getOldValue- null

IsLoad--true

IsLocalLoad-true

IsLocal-false

isGetEntry-false

isSearchOrLoad-true

isUpdate-false

isCreate-true

isDestroy-false

isGet-false

isGetEntry-false

isContainsKey-false

isContainsValue-false

isContainsValueForKey-false

**Scenario -3**

Gemfire - No Record Available

Cassandra - No Record available

Test Case - HTTP PostOperation called using new set of data which is not present in Cassandra and Gemfire

Result - CacheWriterAdapter's beforeCreate() invoked with operation as CREATE

getNewValue- Object fetched

getOldValue- null

IsLoad--false

IsLocalLoad-false

IsLocal-false

isGetEntry-false

isNetLoad-false

isSearchOrLoad-false

isUpdate-false

isCreate-true

isDestroy-false

isGet-false

isGetEntry-false

isContainsKey-false

isContainsValue-false

isContainsValueForKey-false

isInvalidate-false

**Scenario -4**

Gemfire -  Record Available

Cassandra - Record available

Application - HTTP PutOperation  called using existing data which is available in Cassandra and Gemfire

Result - CacheWriterAdapter's beforeCreate() invoked with operation as CREATE

getNewValue- Object fetched

getOldValue- null

IsLoad--false

IsLocalLoad-false

IsLocal-false

isGetEntry-false

isNetLoad-false

isSearchOrLoad-false

isUpdate-false

isCreate-true

isDestroy-false

isGet-false

isGetEntry-false

isContainsKey-false

isContainsValue-false

isContainsValueForKey-false

isInvalidate-false

**Scenario -5**

Gemfire -  Record Available

Cassandra - Record available

Application - HTTP DeleteOperation called using existing IMEI which is available in Cassandra and Gemfire

Result - CacheWriterAdapter's beforeDestroy() invoked with operation as  DESTROY.

getNewValue- Object fetched

getOldValue- null

IsLoad--false

IsLocalLoad-false

IsLocal-false

isGetEntry-false

isNetLoad-false

isSearchOrLoad-false

isUpdate-false

isCreate-false

isDestroy-true

isGet-false

isGetEntry-false

isContainsKey-false

isContainsValue-false

isContainsValueForKey-false

isInvalidate-false

Is this the correct behavior?